# What does the do |t| do when creating tables with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I see the following code in [this ruby on rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html):

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What I can't figure out is what that "do |t|" is for.  What good does it do?

Comment: It's a block, which is a feature of the Ruby language. They're basically lambdas.

Comment: They're not lambdas. `lambda`s are lambdas. That's different from a `Proc` which is what a block is an instance of: `def x(&b); b.class; end; x { } # => Proc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `block` (in this case, anonymous method) to `create_table`, and `create_table` is giving you back an instance of a table definition. You are capturing that table definition when you specify the first argument of your block as `t`. Check out the source here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table

More specifically:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5a31d6340f0ee9f3ff071206b114c0d0a5e52b8e/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L173

```
def create_table(table_name, options = {})
  td = create_table_definition table_name, options[:temporary], options[:options]

  # blah blah

  yield td if block_given?

  # blah blah
end
```

On line 184, we `yield` that table definition to your anonymous function (`block`). This is basically what's happening:

```
def create_table(table_name, options = {})
  td = create_table_definition table_name, options[:temporary], options[:options]

  # blah blah

  # YOUR BLOCK
  td.string :name
  td.text :description

  td.timestamps
  # END BLOCK

  # blah blah
end
```